# Is there any way to install emulator without using wine?

Tags: wine

I need it to practice 16bit assembly code. I care about seeing what happens on the registers, at every instruction execution.Iam using ubuntu 18.04
I was unable to install wine due to broken package issues i tried many things but nothing worked.
my source.list file

[image: my source.list file]

[image: source.list]

remaining code

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
# deb-src http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Comment: You should provide a paste of your command & messages, and I see no reason for the use of `wine` unless you want to use a specific program that was designed for execution on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOSBox with TASM(an x86-16 assembler/debugger).
To install the current version of DOSBox on Ubuntu:

1. Install DOSBox

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dosbox
   ```
2. Download TASM(Turbo Assembler) and TD(Turbo Debugger)

   > *Get a source for this*
3. Extract it to a known location, like `/home/user/tasm`
4. Open DOSBox
5. Mount the path in DOSBox with

   ```
   mount c /home/user/tasm
   ```
6. Execute and enjoy

There were several tutorials on the www, but I didn't succeed in finding one that is still complete and available. Partial solutions can be found [here](https://nagesh-uluvar.blogspot.com/2016/05/masmtasm-in-ubuntu-14.html) or [here](http://lifepluslinux.blogspot.com/2013/03/installing-turbo-assembler-tasm-turbo.html). But both are without pictures.